# Absorption and Distribution Laws and dealing with breaks

Tags: java, arrays, random, numbers

You'll assign the password to a variable, And the user will be prompted to enter a password. Their attempt is assigned to another variable and you'll compare them. If they don't match "INVALID" is displayed and they will continue to be prompted for a password until the correct one is entered.

```
package arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class searchingalgorithms {

public static void main(String[] args){

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int password= 9320;
    int user = 0;

    System.out.print("Enter a password: :");
    user = sc.nextInt();

    if(user==password){
        System.out.println("Valid");
    }

    if(user!=password){
        System.out.println("INVALID");
        user = sc.nextInt();
    }
}
```

}

Hi so, my program works the first time if it is valid but, it just keeps on going on and on.  Also, What I want my program to do is repeat the program if it is invalid.  How do I do this?

Comment: `public static void main(String[] args){

     Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
     int password= 9320;
     int user = 0;

     System.out.print("Enter a password: :");
     user = sc.nextInt();


     while(user!=password){
         System.out.println("INVALID");
         System.out.print("Enter a password: :");
         user = sc.nextInt();
     }
     System.out.println("Valid");
 }`

Comment: Surely your instructor or your assigned readings covered the concept of loops prior to or in conjunction with this assignment?